# Disputing Duplicate Tag

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, re-open

I am terribly disappointed that my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/854223/50955) has been marked as a duplicate.

Someone [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/852839/50955) for a solution for a popular question that did not use complex arithmetics. Only one solution came close to giving a solution except that one step used a rather remarkable trigonometric identity without proof. For the sake of completion and understanding, I posted a question requesting a proof for this identity. Yes, this identity has appeared here before but, alas, the answers both used complex functions! So now my question has been closed for being a duplicate but I believe I'm asking a significantly different question.

I can not believe 5 people read my question (even with the clearly marked title) is still believe that it had 'already been answered.' Are voters even reading questions anymore or do they simply look at how similar the titles are?

Comment: Alas, it appears that many reviewers vote on proposed duplicates without carefully reading the question and the proposed duplicate. This is one of the many bad side-effects of gamified systems that rewards such activity (with badges, rep, etc).

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Comment: For questions like this, it's much better to use the [dedicated thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes).

Comment: I only searched for disputes/duplicates so the thread never showed. Will use it next time I need. Thanks.